# Include ASP.NET pages from C#

Tags: asp.net, templates, webforms, legacy

In a typical web framework

```
func viewHomepage()
    response.write(template.render("a string variable", ["an", "array"]))
```

is a fairly standard way of calling a templating engine and writing the output out.

Obviously the situation is reversed in ASP.net, since the templating engine sits in front of the code.

I am dealing with a legacy application that can't be rewritten. It's basically a 50 line xxx.aspx with a corresponding 20,000 LOC xxx.aspx.cs. What I want to do is write new "views" as separate ASP.net forms and controls and then include them back into the 
xxx.aspx.cs.

Essentially instead of doing:

```
case "newfeature":
{
    Response.Write("<table>");
    ...
    Response.Write("</table>");
}
break;
```

I want to do

```
case "newfeature":
    Response.Write(THEFUNCTIONIMLOOKINGFOR("newfeature.aspx"));
break;
```

That way there'll be some notion of modularity and it won't be reminiscent of a perl CGI script.

Show me a path to sanity pretty-please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done quite simply by calling the `RenderControl` method.  You just need to pass it an `HtmlTextWriter` instance.

The technique is described here: [4GuysFromRolla.com "Emailing the Rendered Output of an ASP.NET Web Control"](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202938/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/091102-1.aspx)

There's also the [MSDN Reference for the `RenderControl` method](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202938/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/091102-1.aspx).